# No property called 'resource' in MultiResourceItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

In spring Batch doc (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html), under 7.4.3 section it is given that we can set the 'resource' property of MultiResourceItemReader from stepExecutionContext. But there is no property called 'resource' in MultiResourceItemReader, instead it is 'resources'. 
Then how single resource can be set to MultiResourceItemReader from stepExecutionContext which will have single fileName in each context which was set during partitioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead it's called `resources` (which is an array) and it can be set like so:

```
<bean id="multiResourceReader" 
            class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
    <property name="resources" value="file:some/folder/prefix*.csv" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemReader" />
</bean>
```

When partitioning, you would not use a `MultiResourceItemReader`. Instead, just use a `FlatFileItemReader` in step scope.

```
<bean id="flatFileItemReader" scope="step"
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="file:#{stepExecutionContext['FILE.NAME']}">
</bean>
```

Comment: That means, Spring document needs to be corrected/updated.
Thanks for answering @DeanClark.

Comment: Seems like it. Please indicate this answer was correct, so others don't see it as unanswered.